# boundedness of semigroup transition with additional smoothness

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I follow the notation of Salamon '87: [*Infinite Dimensional Linear Systems With Unbounded Control and Observation: A Functional Analytic Approach*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1987-300-02/S0002-9947-1987-0876460-7/S0002-9947-1987-0876460-7.pdf)

Let

$$W\subset H \subset V$$

be Hilbert spaces with continuous, dense injections, and let $A\in \mathcal L(W, H)$ be the generator of a strongly continuous semigroup $S(t) \in \mathcal L (H)$, and consider the abstract differential equation 
$$
\dot x = Ax + f, \quad x(0)=x_0 \in H
$$
for $f \in L^2(0,\infty; W)$.

Then, there are plenty regularity results on *well posedness* that guarantee that the *solution* operator $(f\mapsto x)$ is a bounded linear map from $L^2(0,\infty; V)$ into $L^2(0,\infty; H)$:

But what if I have additional regularity, namely $f \in L^2(0,\infty; H)$ and $x_0 \in W$. Can I get an estimate like, for any $T>0$,

$$
\|x(t)\|_{L^2(0,T;W)} \leq c \|u(t)\|_{L^2(0,T;H)}\quad (?)
$$

Any hint or references? An example for $W\subset H \subset V$ is $H^1 \subset L^2 \subset H^{-1}$.